# elasticsearch filter by average min_socre

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch query that has `min_score` set to some value. I am curious if there is an approach to set `min_score` to dynamic value that will set `min_score` to an average of all scores. Or is there any approach to do this stuff without sending two requests (one to get all the scores, calculate average and second to input min_score abased on calculated average)
Or, alternatively, can i normalise scores between 1 and 0 without using two queries?

I've tried sending two requests, as I described in the question. As result, my approach takes too much time.